# access the element in list of dictionary in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

hi every one i have list of dictionary all of the dictionaries like this:

```
 dict1 = {Label:----,Chapter:----,Section:----,Massage:----}
 dict2 = {Label:----,Chapter:----,Section:----,Massage:----}
 dict3 = {Label:----,Chapter:----,Section:----,Massage:----}
 List = [dict1 , dict2 , dict3]
```

i want first the all  dictionaries of list if the my label is equal with label in dictionary print the massage of that dictionary.

i use this method but it get nothing.

```
def printMassage(List , mylabel):
    for dicts in List:
        if (Label.value == mylabel):
            print( Massage.value)
```

please help me!!

Comment: Replace the third line with `if (dicts['Label'] == mylabel):` and forth line with `print( dicts['Massage'])`. You will get what you want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### How dictionary in python works

```
value = dictionary[key]  # get the `value` of `key` in `dictionary`.
dictionary[key] = newvalue  # change the content of `key` in `dictionary` to `newvalue`.
```

#### Your example

```
def printMassage(List , mylabel):
    for dict in List:
        if (dict["Label"] == mylabel):
            print(dict["Massage"])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def printMassage(List , mylabel):
    for dicts in List:
        if dicts[Label] == mylabel:
            print(dicts[Massage])
```

Comment: When your mobile is so slow that while answering the question, two other people finish answering it. :/

Answer (score 0):

When accessing values in dictionaries, you need to use the key as the lookup:

```
def printMassage(List , mylabel):
    for d in List:
        if d['Label'] == mylabel:
            print(d['Massage'])
```

A one-liner:

```
def printMassage(List , mylabel):
    print([d['Massage'] for d in List if d[Label] == mylabel])
```